# How to position Google.visualization.LineChart correctly inside the div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-visualization

I'm trying to place the line chart inside the `div`, but it still leaks below the `div`.

I've already changed the `width` and `top` in the `options`, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

How can I fix those graphics that are outside the `div` to stay inside?

```css
.containerGeral {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 540px); /* The width */
  grid-auto-rows: 250px; /* The height */
  grid-auto-flow: dense; /*This is the important property*/
  /* The margin */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.containerGeral .blocks {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2E5173;
}

.containerGeral .blocks::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.big {
  grid-column: span 3;
  /* Take twice the width*/
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="test">
  </div>
  <div class="containerGeral">
  </div>
  <script>
    function draw(id) {
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        var options = {
          title: 'title',
          curveType: 'function',
          colors: ['#0409BA', '#00930A'],
          lineWidth: 3,
          vAxis: {
            viewWindow: {
              min: 0,
              max: 100
            }
          },
          legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
          },
          top: '0',
          width: '100%',
          heigth: '30'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(id));
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['x', 'y'],
          [0, 0],
          [1, 1],
          [2, 3],
          [3, 7],
          [4, 15],
          [5, 31]
        ]);
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
      if (i % 6 == 0 && i > 0) {
        var d1 = $('<div class="big blocks" id="a' + i + '">titlee' + i + '</div>').appendTo('.containerGeral')
        var d2 = $('<div class="big blocks" id="b' + i + '">titlee' + i + '</div>').appendTo('.containerGeral')
        continue
      }
      $('<div class="blocks" id="c' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('.containerGeral')
      draw('c' + i)
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the pseudo element `::before`

```
.containerGeral .blocks::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

Here is a snippet

```js
function draw(id) {
  google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
  });
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    var options = {
      title: 'title',
      curveType: 'function',
      colors: ['#0409BA', '#00930A'],
      lineWidth: 3,
      vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0,
          max: 100
        }
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom'
      },
      top: '0',
      width: '100%',
      heigth: '30'
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById(id));
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['x', 'y'],
      [0, 0],
      [1, 1],
      [2, 3],
      [3, 7],
      [4, 15],
      [5, 31]
    ]);
    chart.draw(data, options);
  });
}

for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
  if (i % 6 == 0 && i > 0) {
    var d1 = $('<div class="big blocks" id="a' + i + '">titlee' + i + '</div>').appendTo('.containerGeral')
    var d2 = $('<div class="big blocks" id="b' + i + '">titlee' + i + '</div>').appendTo('.containerGeral')
    continue
  }
  $('<div class="blocks" id="c' + i + '"></div>').appendTo('.containerGeral')
  draw('c' + i)
}
```

```css
.containerGeral {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 540px);
  /* The width */
  grid-auto-rows: 250px;
  /* The height */
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  /*This is the important property*/
  /* The margin */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.containerGeral .blocks {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #2E5173;
}

.big {
  grid-column: span 3;
  /* Take twice the width*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<div id="test">
</div>
<div class="containerGeral">
</div>
```